# Change DEFAULT NAMES in TogetherJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, togetherjs

Is there any provision to change the DEFAULT NAMES in TogetherJS? I have seen the DEFAULT NAMES in peers.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [open source project they are located in the `locale` files.](https://github.com/mozilla/togetherjs/blob/master/togetherjs/locale/en-US.json#L48) and compiled into the `js` file.

You can return your own by creating a script prior to the TogetherJS script file.  Works great if you have your own Identity Server.

```html
<script>
  TogetherJSConfig_getUserName = function () {return 'User Name';};
</script>
<script src="https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs-min.js"></script>
```

You can also create your own random creator simple enough.

#### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/talves/xj2gzbak/)

```js
<script>
  pickRandom = function (array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  };

  var DEFAULT_NICKNAMES = [
    "Mickey Mouse",
    "Donald Duck",
    "Snow White",
    "Sir Goofey",
    "Prince Charming"
  ];

  TogetherJSConfig_getUserName = function () {return pickRandom(DEFAULT_NICKNAMES);};
</script>
<script src="https://togetherjs.com/togetherjs-min.js"></script>
```

#### [Link to Documents of other settings](https://togetherjs.com/docs/#setting-identity-information)

Comment: Programming audio chat, not yet.